# VueJS: Property or method "tagNbr" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm trying to get a value from a VueX store during render at the render of my component. What I see is that i firstly get the error above, and then, the value is correctly updated on the component because I think that the state is well reactive but not initialized when component is rendered.

How can i avoid this error ?

**template:**

```
<span class="kt-widget17__desc">
   {{ carsNumber }}
</span>
```

**script:**

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            carsNumber: this.currentGarage.numberOfTags
        };
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(["currentGarage"]),
    }
};
```

**Error:**

> Property or method "carsNumber" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive..

Answer (score 0):

What I did is I created a setter and getter in computed property, in your case `carsNumber` instead of putting it inside the data property.

```js
computed: {
   ...mapGetters(["currentGarage"]),

   carsNumber: {
      get(){
         return this.currentGarage.numberOfTags
      },
      set(newVal){ // setter can be excluded if not used
         // you can call this.$store.commit('yourMutation', yourValue)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this and now I get this error: `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'numberOfTags' of null"`

Comment: change to arrow function

Comment: Now I get : `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentGarage' of undefined"`

Comment: You need to explicitly define your attribute in your `currentGarage`
also in your getter, you need to return a default value for `numberOfTags`